# Read an undirected graph from a list of edges

Tags: python-3.x, graph, graph-theory

I am having problems with reading an undirected graph from a list of edges. I have my list of edges in a txt file like this:

```
BND IEF 0.943176118
BND LQD 0.885572253
BND TIP 0.83072059
BND TLT 0.897231452
DBC USO 0.885015182
```

etc.

And then my code is:

```
G0 = nx.Graph()

G0 = nx.read_edgelist(place_holder + "edges_for_graph.txt", nodetype = str, data = (('weight', int),))
```

But when I run the code I have this problem:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert weight data 0.943176118 to type <class 'int'>.
```

I have tried changing the txt file (with only one space between each value) but it is not working, Does anyone know how to fix it because the values are int.

Comment: The TypeError: Failed to convert weight data 0.943176118 to type <class 'int'>.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the data snippet, your weights arn't ints. You either convert them to int somehow or instead store them as `float`s (probably the second one is what you want to do as the values seem to be between 0 and 1).

For the first way you could preprocess your file to drop the weigths or transform them to values of 1. But to just read them correctly, you would use `('weight', float)` instead of `('weight', int)` as in the example [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_edgelist.html).